# Searching for two Word wildcard strings that are nested

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

I'm having trouble finding the proper Word wildcard string to find numbers that fit the following patterns:

"NN NN NN" or "NN NN NN.NN" (where N is any number 0-9)

The trouble is the first string is a subset of the second string. My goal is to find a single wildcard string that will capture both. Unfortunately, I need to use an operator that is zero or more occurrences for the ".NN" portion and that doesn't exist.

I'm having to do two searches, and I'm using the following patterns:

**[0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9]{2}?[!0-9]**
[0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}

The problem is that first pattern (in bold). It works well unless I have the number in a table or something and there is nothing after it to match (or not match, if you will) the [!0-9].

Comment: Could you please be more precise about the expectations for that last part of the first wildcard combination: `?[0-9]` Is this supposed to be any character that's not a number, so that would be a space, a period, a paragraph mark...? And what else is "or something" besides a table cell?

Comment: @CindyMeister, thanks for the response. Please note that there is an exclamation point in there. I am trying to avoid it catching only the "01 23 45" if it was part of something like "01 23 45.67" as that would be caught by the second pattern. I am using the ? because if I had a sentence that said "This number is 00 11 22." I would want those numbers to be caught. That means I cannot exclude the period. That pattern, does not work when the only text is the number (and no punctiouation, spaces, etc). I often find that being the case when the number is by itself in a cell of a table. That help?

Comment: Yes, that helps clarify... I think this will require VBA code. Search the second wildcard pattern in the question. When/if found, check the following three characters whether they match (Range.MoveEndWhile, for example). If they do, then don't process that "hit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single *wildcard* Find:

```
[0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9][0-9.]{1,4}
```

or:

```
[0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9]{2}[^s ][0-9][0-9.]{1;4}
```

to capture both. Which you use depends on your regional settings.

Comment: thank you. My only complaint is that if I have a sentence like "This number is 00 11 22." it will grab "00 11 22." but I can deal with that. Unfortunately, though, it would also grab "00 11 2." but I think we're stuck with that given Word's wildcard limitations. So, that or VBA I guess...